# EF Code First. Children collection is null for parent

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a problem with Entity Framework Code First approach in developing tree hierarchies.

I need to store some tree in a database. My table has three fields Id, Name and Parent_Id.
I created the following class in my solution:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public TreeNode()
    {
        Children = new List<TreeNode>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TreeNode> Children { get; set; }

    public virtual TreeNode Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I've added the following configuration for TreeNode class

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<TreeNode>().HasOptional(c => c.Parent)
                    .WithMany(c => c.Children)
                    .Map(m => m.MapKey("Parent_Id"));
```

The issue is that Children is always null when returned by EF.

But if retrieve some child node, get its Parent node via Parent property then Children property is filled correctly.

I'm not sure what's wrong here. Looking for your advise.

**Update:** addition of virtual modifier to navigation properties didn't help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either mark properties as `virtual`, as @Cuong suggested. This will enable lazy-loading (each time when you will try to access Children additional query to server will be executed) :

```
public virtual IList<TreeNode> Children { get; set; }
```

OR eager load children when loading parent:

```
var nodes = context.TreeNodes.Include(n => n.Children);
```

Comment: Thanks. Even with virtual properties Children are not returned.

Comment: @lostaman make sure lazy-loading is enabled for context `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;`

Comment: Thanks @lazyberezovsky. I have this option set to false. I changed it to true and now I'm getting an error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first" when trying to access Children collection.

Comment: One more question. Can I force children loading? I'm aware that it will load the whole structure from database into memory.

Comment: @lostaman sorry, was AFK. Yes, you can force loading children of nodes (that is called [eager loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)) but this will not build whole tree for you - it will pre-load only direct children

Comment: This way if I want to load the whole tree I need to load it manually, right?